# VB Debugging error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When I go to debug my project in visual basic, I get an error message which says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Name Database.exe
>
> Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See
>   Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim member As String = TextBoxName.Text
Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
    ListBoxName.Items.Add(member & " " & TextBoxDate.Text)
    TextBoxDate.Text = ""
    TextBoxName.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonRemove.Click
    ListBoxName.Items.Remove(ListBoxName.SelectedItem)
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCheck.Click
    If ListBoxName.Items.Contains(member & " " & Date.Today.ToString) Then
        MsgBox(ListBoxName.Items.Contains(Date.Today.ToString) & "membership needs to be renewed")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Read the inner exception stack trace.

Comment: this is probably the error: `Dim member As String = TextBoxName.Text` the form is not created yet (not any controls) but you are referencing one of the controls (which is NOTHING).  Declare it, but dont initialize (`member = ...`) until FormLoad

Comment: What are "inner exception stack trace"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Dim member As String = TextBoxName.Text
```

That cannot work, the TextBoxName variable is not initialized yet by the time this assignment is executed.  You must use a constructor, like this:

```
 Dim member As String

 Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    member = TextBoxName.Text
End Sub
```

It is InitializeComponent() that sets the TextBoxName control reference.  Do beware that it is still pretty unlikely to work, the Text property would not have been set by the user yet.  So *member* will contain an empty string.  Unless you gave a value in the designer.  Which suggest that this is more likely to be correct:

```
 Dim member As String = String.Empty
```